# Unity Login Loop w/ nvidia gtx 1070

Tags: drivers, unity, nvidia, login

Last night I ran an upgrade and this morning after a shutdown I am experiencing a login loop (even though I normally don't even have the login screen displayed). I checked .xsession-errors and found the following:

```
openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
cannot connect to brltty at :0
upstart: gnome-session (Unity) main process (4070) terminated with status 1
upstart: unity-settings-daemon main process (4059) killed by TERM signal
upstart: logrotate main process (3887) killed by TERM signal
upstart: bamfdaemon main process (3973) killed by TERM signal
upstart: unity-panel-service main process (4077) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-bluetooth main process (4110) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-power main process (4111) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-datetime main process (4113) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-keyboard main process (4117) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-sound main process (4118) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-printers main process (4121) killed by TERM signal
upstart: indicator-session main process (4123) killed by TERM signal
upstart: Disconnected from notified D-Bus bus
```

I have tried to reboot lighdm, mv .Xauthority into a backup file, reinstalling ubuntu-desktop and ubuntu-session, and chown .Xauthority.

I think it is a graphics driver issue, since when I appear at the login screen my displays arrangement is incorrect (I have two monitors).

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out for myself. As I thought, nvidia drivers were the issue. I looked through a few directories and still had the .run file for the nvidia 367.27 graphics drivers. I removed the current drivers with:

```
    sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

Stopped the current Xsession with:

```
    sudo service lightdm stop
```

and finally just installed the drivers from my downloads folder:

```
    sudo sh ~/Downloads/NVIDIA-Linux-*-367.27.run
```

Ran a sudo reboot and everything is back to normal.